# Enviar datos del mismo formulario a un array

Tags: php

Hola trato de traer los datos de un formulario HTML a una pagina principal, el formulario lo debo poder llenar 'n' cantidad de veces y enviar datos al enviarlo por primera vez funciona pero al enviarlo una segunda el segundo dato sobrescribe el primero lo e intentado con sesiones pero no eh logrado encontrar la solución.

formulario (patrimonio_auto.php)

```
<form action="tu_patrimonio.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<div class="col s4">
   <div class="input-field">
    <input id="txt_compania_auto"  name="txt_compania_auto" type="text" class="validate"  data-length="90" maxlength="90">
    <label for="txt_compania_auto">Compañía</label>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Index

```
<?php session_start();   header("Cache-control: private"); ?>
<?php
if ($_POST['txt_nombre_dependientes']){
    $_SESSION['nombre_dependientes'] = $_POST['txt_nombre_dependientes'];
}else{
    $_SESSION['nombre_dependientes'];
}

if ($_POST['txt_compania_auto']) {
     // $_SESSION['txt_compania_auto'] = $_POST['txt_compania_auto'];
     array_push($_SESSION['txt_compania_auto'],$_POST['txt_compania_auto']);
     echo $_POST['txt_compania_auto'];


}else{
     $_SESSION['txt_compania_auto'];


}
```

Comment: Te aconsejo que uses Ajax para esto. Te va a simplificar muchísimo y podrás actualizar la información en el cliente sin tener que recargar la página.

Comment: lo pensé pero obligatoria mente por como esta pensado el proyecto necesito cambiar a otra pagina.

Comment: Es un requerimiento extraño ¿no? Como si alguien te dice: *esto lo puedo hacer en un viaje de ida y vuelta* y te dicen que no, que hay que hacer tantos viajes de ida y vuelta como pasajeros haya. Consecuencia: gasto de recursos, de tiempo, de combustible, fatiga del conductor (mala experiencia de usuario), etc. ¿Qué justifica ese requerimiento si se puede saber?

Comment: lo que lo justifica es que en el index se visualizan 4 tipos de patrimonios, casa, auto, gmm y vida. cada vez que se registra uno cambia a azul y en el caso del auto sale un indicador de numero arriba para poder seleccionar que autos llevas en la session (no se puede registrar hasta terminar todos los demas campos que son otras pantallas)

Comment: Ok. Pero tú puedes repensar tu index con un escritorio donde tengas todas las herramientas que necesitas para tu trabajo en vez de liarte cambiando de páginas. Incluso puedes ocultar o mostrar ciertos contenidos según los necesites o no y puedes permitir al usuario que desde un solo sitio haga todo lo que tenga que hacer y una vez hecho lo mande al servidor. Es mucho más cómodo así que tener que estar cambiando de página.

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que pides, no te hace falta hacer uso de sesiones. Prueba así:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<div class="col s4">
   <div class="input-field">
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['txt_compania_auto']))
            foreach($_POST['txt_compania_auto'] as $txt)
                echo '<div><input name="txt_compania_auto[]" value="'.$txt.'"></div>';
    ?>
    <input id="txt_compania_auto"  name="txt_compania_auto[]" 
        type="text" class="validate"  data-length="90" maxlength="90"
        autofocus>
    <label for="txt_compania_auto">Compañía</label>
    <button>Enviar</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Cuando tu script de PHP recibe el array `$_POST['txt_compania_auto']` genera de nuevo el formulario teniendo en cuenta todos los envíos anteriores. Como la información queda almacenada en el propio formulario, no necesitas almacenarla en variables de sesión. Esto lo consigues con los corchetes `[]` que añades al final del nombre del campo en el atributo `name="txt_compania_auto[]"`.

Recuerda eliminar el atributo `action` de la etiqueta `form` para que el script PHP se reenvíe los datos del formulario a sí mismo.

Sobre lo que comentas de cambiar a otra página, ¿te has planteado meter este formulario en esa otra página?

Espero que haya resuelto tu problema. Cualquier duda, déjamela en los comentarios y ampliaré la respuesta para aclarártela.

Answer (score 0):

Todo esto lo resolví enviándolo a través de  `localStorage` poniendo un contador y declarando cada una de las variables dejo el ejemplo del carro por si a alguien le puede funcionar:

```
html 
<form action="tu_patrimonio.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<div class="col s4">
   <div class="input-field">
    <input id="txt_compania_auto"  name="txt_compania_auto" type="text" class="validate"  data-length="90" maxlength="90">
    <label for="txt_compania_auto">Compañía</label>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

js
localStorage.setItem('compania'+contadorAuto+'', $('#txt_compania_auto').val());
```

no pongo el contador pues lo hice con php y es un contador común y corriente el cual guardo en un input y traigo su valor con JS